# Take the cell value and add that many rows below

Tags: vba, excel, rows

I have an Excel sheet where I have different numbers in range A1 to A10. I need to take the value from the cell and add that many rows under that cell.

Lets say A1 as 3 as value and macro should add 2 rows below A1.

I have tried using "Rows" function but I couldn't find a way out.

Please help.

Comment: can you show your code so far?

Comment: This was my most successful try of all 

**Rows(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & ActiveCell.Row + ActiveCell.Value - 1).Insert shift:=xlDown**      but this adds cells above the active cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going. Let me know if you need any further help.

```
Sub CellsValue()
    Dim Colm As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Long, deflastrow As Long

    'Get the Position of the Required column which has the numbers that it has to shift towards
    Colm = WorksheetFunction.Match("Cells Value", Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1), 0)

    'Get the lastrow of that column
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, Colm).End(xlUp).Row
    deflastrow = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(1, Colm), Cells(lastrow, Colm)))

    For i = 2 To deflastrow + lastrow
        Range("A" & i + 1).Select
        InsertRow = Range("A" & i).Value

        If InsertRow > 0 Then
            InsertRow = InsertRow - 1
        End If

        If InsertRow = 0 Then
            Range("A" & i + 1).Select
        Else
            For j = 1 To InsertRow
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I have made the change. Now it will work. Kindly accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: The Code works dynamically. It should work irrespective of the number of Rows in Column A. Cells Value is nothing but my Column Header in Column A.

Comment: keep in mind that lastrow will increase by adding rows

Comment: @2red13 Your thoughts now ? I believe this will work. I tested it and it works

Comment: Attention: `Dim lastrow, deflastrow As Long` only declares the last variable as `Long` the other is left as `Variant`. Use `Dim lastrow As Long, deflastrow As Long` to declare both as `Long`!

Comment: @Peh Thanks and I didn't know that. New Learning for me.

Comment: @Sid29 Just for your information. What you did works very well in VB (the real Visual Basic) but it doesn't work in VBA (Office). In VBA the type of every variable needs to be specified else it defaults to `Variant`.

Comment: @Peh Thanks again. I believe after the changes that you have pointed out, it should work in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Const sCol As String = "A"

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sCol).End(xlUp).Row - 1 To 1 Step -1
        With ws.Cells(i, sCol)
            If IsNumeric(.Value) Then
                If .Value - 1 > 0 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.Value - 1).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
            End If
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dim i, max, num As Integer
i = 1
max = 10
Do While i < max
 Range("A" & i).Select
 num = Selection.Value
 Dim x As Integer
 x = 0
 Do While x < num
    i = i + 1
    Range("A" & i).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert
    max = max + 1
    x = x + 1
 Loop
 i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub`

Comment: You know that `Dim i, max, num As Integer` only declares `num` as integer and leaves `i` and `max` as variant? It should be `Dim i as Integer, max as Integer, num As Integer` to declare all three as integer (here VBA is very different from VB!). And you should specify the `shift` argument of [`.Insert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840310.aspx) (If this argument is omitted, Excel decides based on the shape of the range and this could fail!) The answer could need some quality update anyway, just posting bad formatted code is far from a good answer.